# Deleting a broken link Unix

Tags: linux, unix, shell

I want to delete a broken link, but before that I want to confirm if the link file is present in directory. Let's call the link `A`:

```
if [ -a A ] then 
  print 'ya A is ther'
fi
```

But if `A` is a broken link then how can I check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find -L -type l` finds broken symbolic links. First confirm that the file is not a directory or a symbolic link to a directory with `test -d` (if it's a directory, `find` would recurse into it). Thus:

```
is_broken_symlink () {
    case $1 in -*) set "./$1";; esac
    ! [ -d "$1" ] && [ -n "$(find -L "$1" -type l)" ]
}
```

This is prone to a race condition, if the link changes between the call to `test` and the call to `find`. An alternative approach is to tell `find` not to recurse.

```
is_broken_symlink () {
    case $1 in -*) set "./$1";; esac
    [ -n "$(find -L "$1" -type l -print -o -prune)" ]
}
```

Comment: See this unix.stackexchange.com answer as to why using `find -L` to find and delete these might be dangerous: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38691

Comment: @OgrePsalm33 Indeed, thanks for the bug report. There is a way to use `find -L` without recursing though, using `-prune`. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

```
if readlink -qe A > /dev/null; then
    echo "link works"
fi
```

Comment: Note that this assumes (recent-ish) GNU coreutils. There are unix systems without a `readlink` command, or with a `readlink` command that takes different options.

Answer (score 0):

Look at example [7-4 of this page: Testing for broken links](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html#BROKENLINK).