# Delete all broken symbolic links with a line?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, symlink

For a given folder, how can I delete all broken links within it?

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637952/deleting-a-broken-link-unix) that shows how to delete one broken link, but I can't put that together in only one line. Is there a one-liner for this?

A broken symbolic is a link that points to  a file/folder that doesn't exists any longer.

Comment: Straight from "man find": `     find -L /usr/ports/packages -type l -exec rm -- {} +
             Delete all broken symbolic links in /usr/ports/packages.`

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Here's a POSIX way of deleting all broken symbolic links in the current directory, without recursion. It works by telling `find` to traverse symbolic links (`-L`), but stopping (`-prune`) at every directory-or-symbolic-link-to-such.

```
find -L . -name . -o -type d -prune -o -type l -exec rm {} +
```

You can also use a shell loop. The test `-L` matches symbolic links, and `-e` matches existing files (excluding broken symlinks).

```
for x in * .[!.]* ..?*; do if [ -L "$x" ] && ! [ -e "$x" ]; then rm -- "$x"; fi; done
```

If you want to recurse into subdirectories, this technique doesn't work. With GNU find (as found on non-embedded Linux and Cygwin), you can use the `-xtype` predicate to detect broken symbolic links (`-xtype` uses the type of the target for symbolic links, and reports `l` for broken links).

```
find -xtype l -delete
```

POSIXly, you need to combine two tools. You can use `find -type l -exec …` to invoke a command on each symbolic link, and `[ -e "$x" ]` to test whether that link is non-broken.

```
find . -type l -exec sh -c 'for x; do [ -e "$x" ] || rm "$x"; done' _ {} +
```

The simplest solution is to use zsh. To delete all broken symbolic links in the current directory:

```
rm -- *(-@D)
```

The characters in parentheses are [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers): `-` to dereference symlinks, `@` to match only symlinks (the combination `-@` means broken symlinks only), and `D` to match dot files. To recurse into subdirectories, make that:

```
rm -- **/*(-@D)
```

Comment: +1 for really cool zsh example, and overall answer. But same question: Why `rm` and not `unlink`? Isn't there cases where `rm` is unsafe?

Comment: I don't know, I'm just asking because my tentatives used `unlink` instead. I don't know why. Maybe because it is a link? :P anyway, this is other question

Comment: was just looking at this question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34248/how-can-i-find-broken-symlinks and the cautions regarding "find -L" -- not sure if it applies, and don't have time to chase it, but someone may want to consider investigating the potential hazards here.

Comment: @JustJeff The hazard mentioned there is about difficult-to-control recursion. My use of `find -L` here prevents recursion altogether, so there is no such hazard.

Comment: Another option: `find -L /path/to/check -type l -delete` (Source: http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2369/find-broken-symlinks-and-delete-them)

Comment: you forgot to close the if clause in the loop option

Comment: why does this find expression not use -maxdepth to prevent recursion?

Comment: @billycrook I don't understand. Why do you want to use `-maxdepth`?

Comment: Because "In the current directory, without recursion" is the most obvious use of -maxdepth

Comment: @billycrook Oh, for the first one. Because I was giving a POSIX solution and `-maxdepth` isn't in POSIX (yet, I think it's planned to be in SUSv5).

Comment: Your first solution doesn't delete self-referential symlinks: "Too many levels of symbolic links."

Comment: @Geremia A self-referential symlink isn't broken. That solution will indeed report an error if there is a recursive symlink anywhere in the tree.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' How could I delete such symlinks automatedly? thanks

Comment: @Geremia Please search if this has been asked already. If it hasn't, please ask a new question. It's outside the scope of this thread.

Comment: who else keeps coming back here?

Comment: Can anyone help me generalize the proposed solutions for arbitrary paths? I am not able to do this myself. The solutions are difficult to read for beginners, some more explanations would be welcome.

Comment: Is this safe and POSIX? `find -L "$DIR" -wholename "$DIR" -o -type d ...`

Comment: @normanius `-wholename` isn't POSIX. The command is, at least, not safe if `$DIR` contains wildcards. Apart from that, I don't understand what you mean by generalizing this “to arbitrary paths” since my answer doesn't use a specific path. You should ask a new question where you explain what you want to do.

Answer (score 32):

Simple answer based on the answer you linked (for a given directory, `$DIR`):

```
find -L $DIR -maxdepth 1 -type l -delete
```

Comment: I like this the best. Even the find man page seems to imply this is a solution for finding broken symlinks.

Comment: On Mac OS (BSD `find`), @sanmiguel’s command gives an error: `find: -delete: forbidden when symlinks are followed`

Comment: Works like a charm in CentOS

Comment: What does the type -l signify here? I thought find -L was only looking at Links, but omitting the -type l flag seems to change the results.

Comment: @JDub9 it's the difference between where to look and what to match when you look there. -L is where to look: include the contents of symlinked dirs. -type l is what to match: symlinks found when looking.

Comment: @jDub9 `-L` tells `find` to return info on the file a symlink points to, or the symlink itself if the file it points to does not exist. `-type l` returns only matches that are symlinks, which immediately filters out any link targets that exist, leaving only symlinks that point to a non-existent file.

Comment: Thanks @sanmiguel. That helps!

Answer (score 10):

For **MAC**, do a dry run as follows:-

```
DIR=<some path>
find -L $DIR -maxdepth 1 -type l -print
```

Now, you can prune the old symlinks as follows:-

```
for f in `find -L $DIR -maxdepth 1 -type l`; do unlink $f; done
```

Comment: Great but doesn't handle directory names with a space.

Comment: ... which is why `"$VAR"` references in the shell should habitually be put into double quotes, except you know exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 9):

From `man find` EXAMPLES:

```
find -L /usr/ports/packages -type l -exec rm -- {} +
```

> **Delete all broken symbolic links in /usr/ports/packages.**

Comment: `find -L /usr/ports/packages -type l -print -delete`

Answer (score 8):

The package [`symlinks`](https://pkgs.org/download/symlinks) is pre-installed on many distributions (including Ubuntu 16.04 & Fedora 25) and has some really useful features, one of which does precisely what you're looking for:

```
symlinks -d ./
```

```
    -d == delete dangling links
```

Comment: symlinks is not preinstalled on CentOS 7.3 or Ubuntu 14. Ubuntu 16 has kernel 4.10 which has this problem: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/linux.kernel/C1Uk5cnrPgs. Of course, if you're not running an SSL server, then Ubuntu 16 is probably fine.

Comment: Also available on Mac OS X: `sudo port install symlinks`

Answer (score 7):

Answer based on the accepted answer to the question question ["How can I find broken symlinks"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38691/83167):

```
find . -type l -! -exec test -e {} \; -print | xargs rm
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [rmlint](https://github.com/sahib/rmlint).

First, change directory to the folder that contains broken  symlinks, and then 
run the following commands *to find bad symlinks pointing nowhere*:

```
rmlint --types="badlinks"
```

Then `rmlint` will create a bash script `rmlint.sh` in your current directory and print a list of bad symlinks in your terminal. To delete all the bad symlinks in your current directory, you can run

```
./rmlint.sh
```

Not exactly one liner, but it is very easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `readlink` to determine if a symlink is broken or not.

The following would list all the broken symlinks in a given directory (and subdirectories):

```
find . -type l -exec sh -c 'readlink -f "{}" 1>/dev/null || echo "{}"' -- "{}" \;
```

Replace `echo` with `rm` to get rid of the broken ones!

(I've redirected the output of `readlink` to `/dev/null` so as to avoid confusion; it'd list the target for the symlinks.)

Comment: By you nickname, I see you like redirecting to /dev/null :-) Thanks, what about `unlink`?

Comment: @fotanus Why `unlink`, what's the problem with `rm`?

Comment: @fotanus BTW, as mentioned, in this case redirecting to `/dev/null` was purely to avoid confusion.  Even if you don't, and replace `echo` with `rm`, it won't cause any sideeffect.

Comment: not sure.. because it is a link? :P I know it only removes the entry point, but isn't somewhat safer than rm?

Comment: It seems you misunderstood what `unlink` does. It also deletes files. However `unlink`, as by POSIX, is supposed to only call the syscall `unlink` and not do anything else, while `rm` has more options and can do other things such as asking interactively confirming the delete. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151951/what-is-the-difference-between-rm-and-unlink).

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on [@sanmiguel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24/sanmiguel)'s but with [fd](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd)

```
fd -tl -L $DIR -X rm
```